# Regex Social Security number validation with dummy characters

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation

I am modifying existing code that displays a SS#. I am trying to figure out the existing validation although I know next to nothing about regular expressions. What I need to do is refactor the existing validation to ALSO accept dummy characters (probably upper-case "X") for the first 5 places, displaying only the last 4 effectively. All this w/o messing up the existing validation. What I pass into the control will depend on roles within the application, either the full number, 000000000 or XXXXX0000. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="SSN" runat="server" CssClass="ContractTextEntry" 
            MaxLength="9" Width="145px" AutoPostBack="True" 
  ValidationSettings-RegularExpression-ValidationExpression="^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)\d{3}([- ]?)(?!00)\d{2}\1(?!0000)\d{4}$">
   <MaskSettings Mask="000-00-0000" PromptChar=" " />
   <ValidationSettings SetFocusOnError="True">
     <RegularExpression ErrorText="Please enter a valid SSN" />
   </ValidationSettings>
 </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to accept X as well as a digit in your first 5 numerals then its a fairly straightforward modification:

```
^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)[X0-9]{3}([- ]?)(?!00)[X0-9]{2}\1(?!0000)\d{4}$
```

all I've done is replace a couple of instances of `\d` (meaning any digit) with `[X0-9]` (meaning X or a character in the range 0-9)

FYI - the {3} following the first means repeated 3 times (and the {2} on the 2nd instance means repeated 2 times)

Comment: In this case, being a devex control, I also had to refactor the MaskSettings to "AAA-AA-0000". Extra points for your explanation. Works great, thanx!

Comment: Would `[X\d]` be valid as well?

Comment: Darkloki you're welcome :), @newbiedoodle - Yes it would be, I'm just used to using ranges inside character classes!

Answer (score 1):

Since you require a few things, either all the first 5 are X's or they're all digits.
I think Dot-Net supports conditionals, but not sure if group number match.
I know it supports group name conditional.

```
 #  ^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)(?:(XXX)|\d{3})([- ]?)(?!00)(?(1)XX|\d{2})\2(?!0000)\d{4}$

 ^ 
 (?! 000 )
 (?! 666 )
 (?! 9 )
 (?:
      ( XXX )          # (1), XXX
   |  \d{3}            # Or digits
 )
 ( [- ]? )             # (2), Separator
 (?! 00 )
 (?(1)                 # Conditional, did group 1 match ?
      XX               # yes, get  XX
   |  \d{2}            # no, get digits
 )
 \2                    # Backref to separator
 (?! 0000 )
 \d{4} 
 $
```